# Entity Framework 6 DbContext slow in selecting data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

We are in the process of moving an old application developed in ASP.NET WebForms and Entity Framework 5 (`ObjectContext`) to ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework 6 (`DbContext`) with a code-first approach from existing database which basically means there will be no `EDMX` file.

This is the generated context class:

```
public partial class MyEntities: DbContext
{
    public MyEntities() : base("name=MyEntities")
    {
    }

    // All the dbset properties here which are automatically generated
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         // All the model builder rules which are automatically generated
    }
}
```

This is one of the auto generated entity model classes I am trying to query and get a list:

```
public partial class MyEntity
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public MyEntity()
    {
        ReportKeyGroupDetails = new HashSet<GroupDetail>();
        SubscriptionKeys = new HashSet<SubscriptionKey>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(1)]
    public string Active { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string DLName { get; set; }

    public virtual Master Master { get; set; } //Navigation property to another Entity

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<GroupDetail> GroupDetails { get; set; }  //Navigation property to another list of Entities

    public virtual TypeMaster TypeMaster { get; set; } //Navigation property to another Entity

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<SubscriptionKey> SubscriptionKeys { get; set; } //Navigation property to another list of Entities
}
```

The table has around 11500 rows in the database.

I am writing this linq query to get the list:

```
var result = context.MyEntities.Where(x => x.Master.MasterID == 1 && x.TypeMaster.TypeMasterID == 1).ToList();
```

This query is fetching 11500 records from the database.

The issue I am facing is the above query is taking more than 20 seconds to execute and fetch the results. When I run the same query in the old project which is using Entity Framework 5 with `ObjectContext`, the query executes in 2 seconds and fetches all 11500 records though it is not populating the `navigation properties`

I have tried setting `LazyLoadingEnabled` and `ProxyCreationEnabled` properties of `DbContext` to `false`, projecting the query to an anonymous type by selecting only the required columns, still is takes more than 20 seconds to execute and fetch the records.

How can I fix this issue?

**EDIT:**

I have tried `.AsNoTracking()` as suggested in comments but this is also giving the same result. I also tried with `LINQPad` and the query is taking almost one minute to execute there, following is the SQL that is generated in `LINQPad`:

```
select cast(serverproperty('EngineEdition') as int)
GO

IF db_id(N'MyDB') IS NOT NULL SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT Count(*) FROM sys.databases WHERE [name]=N'MyDB'
GO


SELECT Count(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t
WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + t.TABLE_NAME IN ('dbo.MyEntity',other table etc...)
    OR t.TABLE_NAME = 'EdmMetadata'
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p__linq__0 NVarChar(1000) = 'UserQuery'
-- EndRegion
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ContextKey] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
GO

SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
GO

SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[ModelHash] AS [ModelHash]
    FROM [dbo].[EdmMetadata] AS [Extent1]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] DESC
GO

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[MyDBKeyMasterID] AS [MyDBKeyMasterID], 
    [Extent1].[MyDBKeyTypeMasterID] AS [MyDBKeyTypeMasterID], 
    [Extent1].[RegionMasterID] AS [RegionMasterID], 
    [Extent1].[KeyValue] AS [KeyValue], 
    [Extent1].[PMEmail] AS [PMEmail]
    FROM [dbo].[MyDBKeyMaster] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE 1 =  CAST( [Extent1].[RegionMasterID] AS int) AND    
    1 =  CAST( [Extent1].[MyDBKeyTypeMasterID] AS int)
```

The last `select` statement is the select query which is fetching the required 11500 records and is taking less than two seconds to run. Also the `__MigrationHistory` table is referenced above but I have not used any migrations with EntityFramework 6, may be this is causing the issue? How to disable it completely?

I have used `Code first from existing database` template to generate the `DbContext` class and the entity models.

**EDIT2:**

I think I have found what is causing the performance issue. We are implementing the `Generic Repository` pattern on the entity models and we are passing the `where` clause of the lambda expressions like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ConcreteEntity> GetMany(Func<ConcreteEntity, bool> where)
{
    return this._context.ConcreteEntity.Where(where).ToList();
}
```

When I pass the where condition as `Func<ConcreteEntity, bool>` type parameter to the above method it is causing a huge performance penalty for some odd reason. If I give the where condition directly in in the `.Where(<some condition>)`, then there is no performance penalty. What could be causing this?

Comment: While it sure is weird that it takes that much longer, but why do you even need to load 11500 rows at once? What do you do with the data? Because either displaying all of those rows at once seems like a bad idea, as does trying to iterate over them to aggregate some kind of information (this is usually much faster written as a query).

Comment: Btw, you can also try [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) (just add the dll containing your Context) to see what the SQL looks like that's generated by your query. It's also very handy to test new queries while development anyways.

Comment: if it's only for read, no update/delete..., try to use TableNoTracking for better performance. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking  And you'd better use stored proc for this, omit big size field like string if not needed in the result.

Comment: @namvo This is about EF 6, not core, though the same advice applies ofcourse. This is the correct link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj556203(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I have edited the question after trying `NoTracking()` and `LINQPad` to see the generated SQL

Comment: You can try removing lazy load to that query, just put `context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` before the query. If you want a specific relation included just add `.include(x => x.TypeMaster)` to the query.

Comment: Where did you add the .AsNoTracking()? You should usually put it before your .ToList(). Also what's the datatype of your foreign keys? Because the cast seems a bit weird to me.

Comment: @Staeff I added `AsNoTracking()` before the where condition and after the dbset propertyname and I also tested with setting LazyLoadingEnabled to false, result is same

Comment: @seadrag0n how are your load times in LinqPad with AsNoTracking() and without it on your query without the Where?

Comment: @Staeff, I think I have found what is causing the performance issue and updated the question...

Comment: In regards to your edit, does the query syntax change between the generic and the direct implementations?  That might give you a better clue as to what EF is trying to do.

Comment: @Staeff yes it actually does...I just checked and the parameter type for the `where` clause is `Expression<Func<ConcreteEntity, bool>>` and not `Func<ConcreteEntity, bool>` which was causing the performance issue...its very weird that no exception was thrown because of this...anyway my issue is fixed now...should I post this as an answer and accept it?